# How to export firebase database using firebase cli when payload is too large?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to export a firebase database from the command-line using firebase CLI. When I run the database:get command I get

`Error: HTTP Error: 413, Payload is too large`

Is there a way to export the database from cli without breaking it up into smaller collections?

Comment: Write your own program that listens to the root node?

Comment: this makes me mad!! no solutions?

Comment: This is old and I forgot about it but - I ended up writing a bash script to run the command on each collection separately to get the data. There were sections that were again too large so I had to break those up further. The export command on Firebase also would time out, so I think this is the only way to get the data haha

Comment: would be useful to include your bash script as that might help others with the same problem